# Producing smmary tables for very large datasets

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with migration data, and I want to produce three summary tables from a very large dataset (>4 million).  An example of which is detailed below:

```
migration <- structure(list(area.old = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                   2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("leeds", 
                                                                                                                   "london", "plymouth"), class = "factor"), area.new = structure(c(7L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    13L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("bath", "bristol", "cambridge", "glasgow", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              "harrogate", "leeds", "london", "manchester", "newcastle", "oxford", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              "plymouth", "poole", "york"), class = "factor"), persons = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           9L, 4L)), .Names = c("area.old", "area.new", "persons"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -19L))
```

**Summary table 1: 'area.within'**

The first table I wish to create is called 'area.within'.  This will detail only areas where people have moved within the same area (i.e. it will count the total number of persons where 'london' is noted down in 'area.old' and 'area.new').  There will probably be multiple occurrences of this within the data table.  It will then do this for all of the different areas, so the summary would be:

```
      area.within persons
1      london      13
2       leeds       5
3    plymouth       5
```

Using the data table package, I have as far as:

```
setDT(migration)[as.character(area.old)==as.character(area.new)]
```

... but this doesn't get rid of duplicates...

**Summary table 2: 'moved.from'**

The second table will summarise areas which have experienced people moving out (i.e. those unique values in 'area.old').  It will identify areas for which column 1 and 2 are different and add together all the people that are detailed (i.e. excluding those who have moved between areas - in summary table 1).  The resulting table should be:

```
      moved.from persons
1     london      24
2      leeds      17
3   plymouth      19
```

**Summary table 3: 'moved.to'**

The third table summarises which areas have experienced people moving to (i.e. those unique values in 'area.new').  It will identify all the unique areas for which column 1 and 2 are different and add together all the people that are detailed (i.e. excluding those who have moved between areas - in summary table 1).  The resulting table should be:

```
     moved.to persons
1      london       5
2        york       3
3   cambridge       2
4     bristol       5
5     glasgow       6
6       leeds       8
7        york       6
8   harrogate       3
9  manchester       4
10   plymouth       0
11      poole       2
12  newcastle       3
13       bath       4
14     oxford       9
```

Most importantly, a sum of all the persons detailed in tables 2 and 3 should be the same.  And then this value, combined with the persons total for table 1 should equal the sum of the all the persons in the original table.

If anyone could help me sort out how to structure my code using the data table package to produce my tables, I should be most grateful.

Comment: I think there is an error in your third result: row 2 and 7 have __york__ as moved.to. Shoudn't it be `york = 9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` is a good choice i think.

```
setDT(migration) #This has to be done only once
```

## 1.

To avoid duplicates just sum them up by city as follows

```
migration[as.character(area.old)==as.character(area.new), 
                 .(persons = sum(persons)), 
                 by=.(area.within = area.new)]
```

## 2.

This is very similar to the 1. one but uses `!=` in the **i**-Argument

```
migration[as.character(area.old)!=as.character(area.new), 
                 .(persons = sum(persons)), 
                 by=.(moved.from = area.old)]
```

## 3.

Same as 2.

```
migration[as.character(area.old)!=as.character(area.new), 
                 .(persons = sum(persons)), 
                 by=.(moved.to = area.new)]
```

**Alternative**
As 2. and 3. are very similar you can also do:

```
moved <- migration[as.character(area.old)!=as.character(area.new)]
#2
moved[,.(persons = sum(persons)), by=.(moved.from = area.old)]
#3
moved[,.(persons = sum(persons)), by=.(moved.to = area.new)]
```

Thus only once the selection of the right rows has to be done.