# Including NAs in summary tables

Tags: r, data.table

For a sample dataframe:

```
migration <- structure(list(area.old = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
                                               3L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("leeds", "london", "plymouth"), class = "factor"), 
                        area.new = structure(c(7L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
                                               13L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 11L, NA, NA, NA, 
                                               NA, 7L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("bath", "bristol", "cambridge", 
                                                                           "glasgow", "harrogate", "leeds", "london", "manchester", 
                                                                           "newcastle", "oxford", "plymouth", "poole", "york"), class = "factor"), 
                        persons = c(6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 4L, 7L)), .Names = c("area.old", 
                                                                                                           "area.new", "persons"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        -26L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>)
```

I wish to summarise the data into a couple of dataframes using the code:

```
moved.from <- migration[as.character(area.old)!=as.character(area.new), 
                 .(persons = sum(persons)), 
                 by=.(moved.from = area.old)]

moved.to <- migration[as.character(area.old)!=as.character(area.new), 
                 .(persons = sum(persons)), 
                 by=.(moved.to = area.new)]
```

This produces two summary tables, firstly detailing the total of people who have moved from the areas in 'area.old'.  The second table lists the destinations people have moved to (in 'area.new').  This code was kindly suggested here ([Producing smmary tables for very large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761936/producing-smmary-tables-for-very-large-datasets)).

When I tried it out on my own data there was a problem as I wasn't telling R how to deal with the NAs in 'area.old' or 'area.new' columns.  How could I modify this code to add all the NAs in as well (i.e. include them in a row at the bottom of the moved.from and moved.to data frames adding the total number of persons in the NAs)?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `| is.na` as additional condition within each filter

```
migration[as.character(area.old) != 
            as.character(area.new) | 
            is.na(area.old),
          .(persons = sum(persons)), 
          by = .(moved.from = area.old)]

#    moved.from persons
# 1:     london      24
# 2:      leeds      17
# 3:   plymouth      19
# 4:         NA      26
```

And

```
migration[as.character(area.old) !=
            as.character(area.new) |
            is.na(area.new), 
          .(persons = sum(persons)), 
          by = .(moved.to = area.new)]

#       moved.to persons
#  1:       york       9
#  2:  cambridge       2
#  3:    bristol       5
#  4:    glasgow       6
#  5:      leeds       8
#  6:     london       5
#  7:  harrogate       3
#  8: manchester       4
#  9:      poole       2
# 10:  newcastle       3
# 11:       bath       4
# 12:     oxford       9
# 13:         NA      31
```

---

As a side note, I'd recommend to convert your two columns into character class and avoid calling `as.character` within each operation. The following should do

```
migration[, names(migration)[-3L] := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = -"persons"]
```

Now you can compare the `area.old` and `area.new` without calling `as.character`